# Renderer Angular 4 not working with cursors style

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problems with angular 4.

In child component i have a subject(Rxjs) to raise event like that:

```
 this._commonService.changeMouseMode.next(mouseMode.panning);
```

In parrent component i have method subcribe it to change cursor style like this:

```js
private subcribeMouseMode(value) {
    if (this._isFirstRender) { return; }
    switch (value) {
      case mouseMode.none:
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
          this._renderer.setStyle(this._rootElement, 'cursor', 'default');
        });
        break;

      case mouseMode.panning:
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
          this._renderer.setStyle(this._rootElement, 'cursor', 'url(./../../../../../../assets/img/icon/icons8-Hand-30.png), auto');

        });
        // this._renderer.setStyle(this._rootElement, 'cursor', 'crosshair');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

I use renderer2 but the current cursor not change. I don't know where the problem. Help me please.

Many thanks

Comment: Why are the functions being executed inside ngZone.run methods? Is the host method inside an ngZone.runOutsideAngular(  method?

Comment: Why you need to do this with angular?
You can do this using css

Comment: I just tested it with Renderer2 and it worked for me, so I guess we at least know that Renderer can be used to change mouse styles to images.  :-p  Maybe its a problem with your file path. I'm not sure if Angular is able to look outside its own app directory scope as far as local files go, and seeing your assets folder so many folders down makes me wonder if that's what you're trying to do? I dunno. I agree w/ the above commenter though, if you need a style to toggle based on an observable, i'd just toggle a class on and off that has the style specified (if feasible).

Comment: I use angular because i change cursor when i run some angular function.
Thanks for your help i will try.

Comment: @ diopside i use runOutsideAngular it not work too sir :(

Comment: Well I ask because you shouldn't ever use 'ngZone.run(' unless you're  doing so from *within* a ngZone.runOutsideAngular(' method. All ngZone.run does is restore the scope back to Angular when it was reomved with run outside angular. I would remove any ngZone.run( methods you have. Maybe that would help?  I dunno why it would but it cant hurt.